# ES6: callback functions between objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm building a page that will have various 'sections' that the user will pass through, each with their own logic. For instance:

1. Loading section: loading blinker. When finished, continue to:
2. Splash section: an introduction with some UI elements that need to be interacted with to continue. (let's just say there's a 'slide to unlock')
3. Video premiere: a custom player using the Youtube embed Javascript API.

Since some of these sections have a lot of specific logic, I'm separating these out into components. Almost all of this logic is internal to the component, but occasionally, I'd like to call a function within component A from component B. See the latter lines of **main.js** and **Splash.js**

**main.js**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import Loading from './components/Loading.js';
import Splash from './components/Splash.js';
import Premiere from './components/Premiere.js';

$(() => {
    Loading.init();
    Splash.init();
    Premiere.init();

    Splash.onUnlock = Premiere.playVideo;
});
```

**Loading.js:**

```
const Loading = {
    init() {
        // watches for events, controls loading UI, etc.
    },
    // ... other functions for this section
}
export default Loading;
```

**Splash.js**

```
const Splash = {
    init() {
        // watches for events, controls unlocking UX, etc.
    },
    // ... other functions for this section
    unlock() {
        // called when UX is completed
        this.onUnlock();
    }
}
export default Splash;
```

**Premiere.js**

```
const Premiere = {
    init() {
        this.video = $('#premiereVideo');
        // watches for events, binds API & player controls, etc.
    },
    // ... other functions for this section
    playVideo() {
        this.video.play()
    },
}
export default Premiere;
```

Now, I'd expect that when `this.onUnlock()` is called within `Splash`, `Premiere.playVideo()` would be triggered. But, I get an error: `video` is not defined - because it's looking for `Splash.video`, not `Premiere.video`.

From what I understand, assigning an object or its property to a variable creates a *reference* to that property, not a duplicate instance. It seems I'm not understanding this correctly.

Changing `this.video.play()` to `Premiere.video.play()` works, but I feel like I'm still missing the point.

What's up?

(Possibly related sub-question: would I benefit from defining these components as classes, even if they're only going to be used once?)

Comment: Yes they would benefit from being classes, makes it more readable. Secondly it could be due to the `this` not being what you think it is, try `Splash.onUnlock = Premiere.playVideo.bind(Premiere);`

Comment: As long as you're using ES6, look into promises: www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/
Then main can be just be Loading.init().then(Splash.init).then(Premiere.init);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So to answer your question why do you get **video is not defined** is because you are trying to access `this` which has changed contexts.

```
Premiere.playVideo.bind(Premiere)
```

Where the bind will make sure that when `playVideo` is called, it is called in the context of `premiere` rather than the context of `splash`. This means the context of `premiere` has `this.video`.

The code I used to verify:

```
const Splash = {
    init() {
        // watches for events, controls unlocking UX, etc.
    },
    // ... other functions for this section
    unlock() {
        // called when UX is completed
        this.onUnlock();
    }
}

const Premiere = {
    init() {
        this.video = { 
            play() {
                console.log("playing");
            } 
        };
        // watches for events, binds API & player controls, etc.
    },
    // ... other functions for this section
    playVideo() {
        console.log(this);
        
        this.video.play()
    },
}

Premiere.init();
Splash.onUnlock = Premiere.playVideo.bind(Premiere);

console.log(Splash);

Splash.unlock();
```

However, this particular "architecture" is a bit smelly to me. You could use the chain of responsibility pattern. This is where the current object knows what to call next after it has done it's work.

```
class DoWork {
    constructor(nextWorkItem) {
        this.nextWorkItem = nextWorkItem;
    }
    
    doWork() {
        
    }
}

class LoadingComponentHandler extends DoWork {
    constructor(nextWorkItem) {
        super(nextWorkItem);
    }
    
    doWork() {
        // do what you need here
        console.log("Doing loading work")
        
        // at the end call
        this.nextWorkItem.doWork();
    }
}

class SplashComponentHandler extends DoWork {
    constructor(nextWorkItem) {
        super(nextWorkItem);
    }
    
    doWork() {
        // do what you need here
        console.log("Doing Splash Work")
        
        // at the end call
        this.nextWorkItem.doWork();
    }
}

class PremiereComponentHandler extends DoWork {
    constructor(nextWorkItem) {
        super(nextWorkItem);
    }
    
    doWork() {
        // do what you need here
        console.log("Doing Premiere Work")
        
        // at the end call
        this.nextWorkItem.doWork();
    }   
}

class FinishComponentHandler extends DoWork {
    constructor() {
        super(null);
    }
    
    doWork() {
        console.log("End of the line now");
    }
}

var finish = new FinishComponentHandler();
var premiere = new PremiereComponentHandler(finish);
var splash = new SplashComponentHandler(premiere);
var loading = new LoadingComponentHandler(splash);

loading.doWork();
```

The `FinishComponent` is part of the Null Object Pattern, where its implementation does a noop (no operation). This effectively ends the line of responsibility. **Of course you don't need a `FinishComponent`, you can just not call the `this.nextWorkItem.doWork()` and the chain will end there.** I have it there because it is easier to see *where* the chain stops.

You can see from the last four lines that the chain of responsibility is easy to see:

```
var finish = new FinishComponentHandler();
var premiere = new PremiereComponentHandler(finish);
var splash = new SplashComponentHandler(premiere);
var loading = new LoadingComponentHandler(splash);
```

The loading component will call `doWork` on the `splash` object which will in turn call `doWork` on the `premiere` object, so on, so fourth.

This pattern relies on the inheritence of `DoWork` which is the kind of interface for the handler.

This probably isn't the best implementation, but you can see how you don't have to worry about the last thing that was called, or how to specially call the next. You just pass in the object you wish to come next into the constructor and make sure you call at the end of your operations.

I noticed you had

```
// watches for events, controls unlocking UX, etc.
```

The `doWork()` functions can execute the bindings, delegating them to the proper components that deal with this. So like `SplashComponentHandler` can delegate off to `SplashComponent`. It's good practise to keep these separations of concerns.

### How this addresses your issue

```
Splash.onUnlock = Premiere.playVideo.bind(Premiere);
```

Firstly, `Splash.onUnlock` has no implementation until you give it one. Secondly, the fact you're having to bind a context to your function because it is getting executed under a different context doesn't sound good.

So you can imagine in `SplashComponentHandler.doWork()`:

```
doWork() {
    var component = new SplashComponent();

    component.initialise(); // when this is finished we want to execute the premiere
 
    this.nextWorkItem.doWork();
}
```

And in `PremiereComponentHandler.doWork()`:

```
doWork() {
    var component = new PremiereComponent();

    component.bind(); // makes sure there is a this.video.

    component.playVideo();
}
```

See now that `SplashComponentHandler` now has no knowledge of the next handler, it just knows that when it has finished its job, it needs to call the next handler.

There is no `this` binding, because `doWork()` has been executed in the context of `PremiereComponentHandler` or what ever handler was passed to `SplashComponentHandler`.

### Furthermore

Technically speaking, you're not limited to executing one handler after another. You can create a handler that executes many other handlers. Each handler that gets executed will have knowledge of the next one until you stop calling into.

Another question is, *what happens if once premiere is done doing its work, how can splash do something else afterwards?*. Simple, so working from the previous scenario of decoupling, this is `SplashComponentHandler.doWork()`:

```
doWork() {
    var component = new SplashComponent();

    component.initialise(); // when this is finished we want to execute the premiere
 
    this.nextWorkItem.doWork();

    // so when we get to this execution step 
    // the next work item (PremiereComponentHandler)
    // has finished executing. So now you can do something after that.

    component.destroy(); // cleanup after the component

    fetch('api/profile') // i don't know, what ever you want.
        .then(profileContent => {
            component.splashProfile = profileContent.toJson();;
        });
}
```

On that last note of using a `Promise` you can make the whole `doWork()` async using promises. Just return the `this.nextWorkItem.doWork()` and then the initialisation steps look like this:

```
var finish = new FinishComponentHandler();
var premiere = new PremiereComponentHandler(finish);
var splash = new SplashComponentHandler(premiere);
var loading = new LoadingComponentHandler(splash);

loading
   .doWork()
   .then(() => {
       // here we have finished do work asynchronously.
   })
   .catch(() => {
       // there was an error executing a handler.
   });
```

The trick to making it all use `Promises` is to make sure that you always return a promise from `doWork()`.